# How did Oliver Queen get his scars?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, arrow

**Has *Arrow* shown how Oliver Queen got his scars?**

And is there an up-to-date picture of his scars that displays his new ones (like from Ra's)?

Comment: Found [this image](http://25.media.tumblr.com/838bfd98562783e98c77279e954ef577/tumblr_mipgrdnFpg1rajf3no1_1280.jpg) with [some discussion](http://www.reddit.com/r/arrow/comments/22t545/scars_and_tattoos_explanation_timeline/), but it's from almost a year ago and doesn't account for his back scars.

Answer (score 8):

[image: TV Guide image]

For San Diego Comic-Con 2014 (between seasons 2 and 3), TV Guide and Warner Brothers released [a special "Arrow" edition of the magazine](https://www.tvguide.com/news/tv-guide-magazine-1084172/) which included a page just about Oliver's scars. Since it was released prior to the battle with Ra's, it is missing any new scars from recent events, but it stands to reason that all scars left through the end of season 2 are included. It mentions 18 scar appliques that need to be applied.

Add to it, this second fan-compiled image and [discussion on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/arrow/comments/22t545/scars_and_tattoos_explanation_timeline/).

[image: Reddit image with four other scars]

So, putting this together, we have

- front right pec: scar from [Yao Fei](https://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Yao_Fei)'s arrow
- front left stomach: TV guide says these scars from [Billy Wintergreen](https://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Billy_Wintergreen), but Wintergreen stabbed him, and this scar matches up with the shark bite he received in ["Dark Waters"](https://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Waters)
- front left pec: wound from [Moira Queen](https://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Moira)'s gun
- front left pec: unknown scar
- front left shoulder: scar from Yao Fei's arrow
- back upper left - unknown scar (IIRC, I believe these are from torture aboard [Ivo](https://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Anthony_Ivo)/[Slade](https://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Slade_Wilson)'s ship during S2's flashbacks)
- back upper right - whip scars inflicted by [Conklin](https://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Conklin)
- back left-middle - knife slice scars from Bratva initiation trust trial.
- lower back: burn scars
- tattoo, right stomach: mystical tattoo provided by [John Constantine](https://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/John_Constantine)
- tattoo, back upper left - provided by [Shado](https://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Shado)
- tattoo, left pec - Russian Bratva/mafia tattoo

Comment: Those pictures are not up to date. Missing scar from stabbing through himself to injure malcolm and the scar from Ra's. But the show might not of added them as Oliver did not get scars from getting shot in his back with arrows.

Comment: Yes, that's why I wrote "I can't find exactly when TV guide created this image, but here is a map of Oliver's scars on his front and back from before his battle with Ra's."

Comment: We've got a couple of updates recently. Tonight's episode had a shark bite. And Constantine provided the Chinese.

Comment: I don't watch the show but I guess he got some new scars in the last two years. Maybe worth an update?

Answer (score 0):

The arrow scar from Yao Fei is under the burn on his right shoulder. If you watch closely at the end of season 5 when he is back on the island fighting a guy (Konstantin Kovar), the burning plane causes a scar on his back and the one over the arrow one on his right shoulder.

Comment: You've not quite answered how he got his scars as opposed to how he got his burns, what about the ones prior to those burns?

Answer (score -1):

Billy Wintergreen gave a fair few of them to him and the rest he accumulated over time from war wounds.

Comment: Do you have any sources for this?

Comment: The flashback scenes in season one show Billy torturing him, accounting at least for some of the scars. Others are from various battles and time on the boat in the season 2 flashbacks.